# shuffle data in train test split function sklearn returns error

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]]).T
b = np.array([[100,200,50,60,3000]]).T

x1,x2,y1,y2 = tts(a,b, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

print(x1)
print(x2)
print(y1)
print(y2)
```

I always receive following error:

```
builtins.TypeError: Invalid parameters passed: {'shuffle': False}
```

I have checked documentation:

> shuffle : boolean, optional (default=True) Whether or not to shuffle
>   the data before splitting. If shuffle=False then stratify must be
>   None.

added `stratify=None`, but I get still the same error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: must be  the wrong version of sklearn then. check your version by typing `print(sklearn.__version__)`

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich 0.18.1 I think it's the last, let me check for updates

Comment: The last one is 0.19.0. That is the version that the documentation is referring to. The error should go away after you upgrade.

Comment: Thank you @EvgenyTanhilevich

Comment: Please upvote the answer :)

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich, you should move your comments to an answer so that OP can upvote and mark it....Comment +1 is not a valid way to determine an answer on SO

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by outdated version of `sklearn`. The documentation refers to version 0.19.0. The version of `sklearn` that is currently installed can be checked by typing

```
>>> print(sklearn.__version__)
```

Comment: I am getting this error with 0.19.1, can't think of any causes though. EDIT: it's because I was importing the deprecated version, from sklearn.cross_validation rather than sklearn.model_selection. Fixed now